# Laravel Sanctum not Working on Production Server but Works Locally

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-sanctum

Using Laravel Sanctum to Generate tokens for API use in mobile Application. It works well in Local environment using php artisan serve but in production it shows error meesage  *"error": "Unauthenticated."* even after successful login.

The tokens are generated and stored in the database but the request comes out unauthenticated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What code exactly you want to see? API, Route Or Config @

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you are using PHP 7.4+. This is how we solved a similar problem.
Locally, we were using PHP 7.4 but the server run on PHP 7.3. After bumping up the version, Laravel/Sanctum worked like a charm.